# Proving $P((A\cap B^c)\cup C) = ...$

Tags: probability-theory

> Prove that $$P((A\cap B^c)\cup C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) + P(A\cap B \cap C)$$

I know from theorem 1.2.9 in Casella and Berger that $$P(A\cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$$

I am kinda stuck on this one so far I have $$P((A\cap B^c)\cup C) = P((A\cup C)\cap (B^c\cup C))$$ but I am not sure where to go from here.

Just some hints would be appreciated I want to try to do this mostly on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Theorem 1.2.9 is useful.
Another useful formula:

$$P(A \cup B) =P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$

Hence

\begin{align}
P((A \cap B^c) \cup C)=P(A\cap B^c)+P(C)-P(A\cap B^c\cap C)
\end{align}